# How to rotate static image in openlayers 6.x

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6, openlayers-5, turfjs

I need to create and rotate a static image layer in openlayers 6.

The creation of static image is working using url and imageExtent and i can see the image inside the map.

```
new ImageLayer({
        source: new Static({
          url,
          imageExtent: [ minX, minY, maxX, maxY] })
```

Now, I need to rotate this image.

I decided to use [Turfjs](https://github.com/Turfjs)

So i did this code that rotate using transformRotate from Turfjs:

```
 const poly = bboxPolygon([minX, minY, maxX, maxY])

  const rotatedPoly = transformRotate(poly, -extent.rotation, {})



  const leftBottom = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rotatedPoly.geometry.coordinates[0][0]))
  const rightBottom = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rotatedPoly.geometry.coordinates[0][1]))
  const rightTop = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rotatedPoly.geometry.coordinates[0][2]))
  const leftTop = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rotatedPoly.geometry.coordinates[0][3]))

  const bounds = [leftBottom, leftTop, rightTop, rightBottom]

  return new ImageLayer({
    source: new Static({
      url,
      imageExtent: bounds
    })
  })
```

The last block code is not working, i see nothing inside the map.

My coordinates are in 'EPSG:4326'

Any idea please ?.

Any solution that may be help even without Turfjs ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the ol-ext extension and the `ol.source.GeoImage`.

See it in action: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/layer/map.geoimage.html

Comment: not working with openlayers 6.9

Comment: http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/doc/doc-pages/

Comment: Cool extensions for OpenLayers (ol/ol3/ol4).

Comment: The example page runs with the last ol version... the doc is not up to date...

Comment: what is the equivalent of imageExtent of ImageLayer (openlayers) in GeoImage (ol-ext) ?. is same as imageCrop ?. any example please ?

Comment: You can use `ImageCrop` or `ImageMask` option. `ImageCrop` is used in the example page.